# Is disassembly code an accurate option for crash assimilation?

Tags: debugging, assembly, crash, disassembly, crash-dumps

Let's say I have four different dump files. When I open them in a debugger, I get the assembly lines that the program broke into. Two dumps are showing the same assembly lines, the other two are showing different assembly lines.

Does that mean that the first two crashes occurred because of the same line in the code, same exception, in the same call stack?

Please note that I already checked the "[Match source with disassembled code](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23174243/match-source-with-disassembled-code)" question, but I can only work with the dump file. No source code, no symbols, Windows only.

Comment: Same instruction, if the address is the same. Not necessarily the same exception or the same call stack. Obviously you can call a function multiple times from multiple places. Note the call stack (and probably the exception) should be in the dump.